# Inline ReDim a Nested Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vbscript

I want to `ReDim` a nested array (NOT a 2d array, see example).
I run it with a VBS file on Windows 10.

```
'1 standard redim
myArr = Array()
Redim myArr(11)
msgBox(UBound(myArr)) 'show 11

'2 nested this way works
myArr(0) = Array("a", "b", "c")
msgBox(UBound(myArr(0))) 'show 2

'3 ERROR, NOT corresponding type
' myArr(1)(4) 

myArr(2) = Array()
msgBox(UBound(myArr(2))) 'show -1

'4  compiling error
reDim myArr(2)(3)
```

I have a solution that is not inline but uses a helper function:

```
res = reDimmer(myArr(2), 4)
msgBox(UBound(myArr(2))) 'show 4 

function reDimmer(arr, num)
    reDim arr(num)
end function
```

I can't understand if i'm making a syntax error or if there is a limit in VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

`ReDim` can only be used on a variable. You could do the following:

```
Dim temp
temp = myArr(2)
ReDim temp(3)
myArr(2) = temp
```

(But -- I'm not sure why you would want to inline this rather than just use `reDimmer`.)

Comment: I would prefer to do it inline because it avoids rows of code that make the file less readable. An inline syntax is also more flexible, i must do two different functions for a Preserve version.